# start activity with selelcted position item in recycle View

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

**How to start activity with selected card item of Recycle View when app start again.**

**Details:**

I have three activities: **Splash Screen**, **Card List** and **Card Details**.

- **Card List** activity contains list of cards. Every Single item of list has menu. In the menu there's one option which is "Set default card".
- Card Details this activity show details of card.

**Problem:**

Now if I've select Set default card, selected card contains green border.

When I set default card and exit my app, so next if i open my app then it should go to  Card Details activity with selected card.

Note: i use database to store card details and default card

**My code:**

**CardAdapter.class**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private static int lastCheckedPos = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Card> cardsList;
    boolean isError;

    public CardAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Card> cardsList, String key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.cardsList = cardsList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Card card = cardsList.get(position);
        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);

     [enter image description here][1]
        //ustawienie zaznaczenia na wybranej pozycji
        if (position == lastCheckedPos) {

            holder.cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bordercardview);

        } else {

            holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                Typeface custom_fonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
                Typeface custom_fonts_Bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, v);
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.cardmenu);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                            switch (item.getItemId()) {


                                    case R.id.defaultCard:

                                    int prePos = lastCheckedPos;
                                    lastCheckedPos = position;
                                    notifyItemChanged(prePos);
                                    notifyItemChanged(lastCheckedPos);

                                    break;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    popupMenu.show();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardsList.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Store your lastCheckedPos to SharedPreferences and use it to fill the adapter

Answer (score 1):

you can move to particular position by after creating recyclerView:

```
 recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(position);
```